# React state/props won't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have the code below, but my state won't update. 
I am using Angular http ajax-call to receive if the user is correct or not. When I pass the the new error-message as a prop nothing happens, but the component does receive it since I can access it through `nextProps`.

I have also tried to skip the `constructor`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate` to just render out `{ this.props.error }`, but that did not work either.

This is my render-function to render the DOM first time

```
// Some code

.then(function(response){
   // Some code
}, function(response){
   _this.renderLogin("User not found"); // Is sending the error-message to the function 
});

// Some code

_this.renderLogin = function(error){
   render(
      <Login error={error} />,
      document.getElementById("app")
   );
};
_this.renderLogin("Standard");
```

This is the Login-component:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: this.props.error
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.error !== this.state.error) {
            this.setState({ error: nextProps.error });
            console.log(nextProps.error); // User not found 
            console.log(this.state.error); // Standard
        }else{}
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log(nextState.error); // User not found
        console.log(nextProps.error); // User not found
        console.log(this.state.error); // Standard
        return true;
    }

    render(){
       return(
          <div>
             { this.state.error } // Always showing: 'Standard'
          </div>
       );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see of your code `Login` should not be a stateful component since it does nothing to mutate the state... its just setting a prop it receives to its state for no reason. In React state is passed down with props and renders are triggered on components that need updating with the new prop value. Nothing is happening in your code because the component has already been affixed to the DOM, but your're trying to reaffix it to the DOM with a new value with this

`.then(function(response){
   // Some code
}, function(response){
   _this.renderLogin("User not found"); // Is sending the error-message to the function 
});`

Something like that code needs to be within stateful react component that evaluates if the user is logged in or not. The state must be mutated WITHIN a react component and not outside trying to pass it in. In the code below I didn't change your `Login` to be stateless, but it still works because I've muted the value within a React component.

```js
class RenderLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errors: "Standard",
    };
    this.changeError = this.changeError.bind(this); 
 }
  changeError() {
    this.setState({errors:"Boom"});
  }
  
   render() {
     return (
      <div>
      <Login error={this.state.errors} />
      <button onClick={this.changeError}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
   }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: this.props.error
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.error !== this.state.error) {
            this.setState({ error: nextProps.error });
            console.log(nextProps.error); // User not found 
            console.log(this.state.error); // Standard
        }else{}
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log(nextState.error); // User not found
        console.log(nextProps.error); // User not found
        console.log(this.state.error); // Standard
        return true;
    }

    render(){
       return(
          <div>
             { this.state.error } // Always showing: 'Standard'
          </div>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RenderLogin />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: true -->

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a well described answer. It makes sense :)